# How to get the index of ListModel delegate loaded with Loader?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a component in which there's a ListView and a Loader:

```
// MyComponent.qml
Component {
    property myDelegate: Component {}
    ListView {
        id: myListView
        width: ...
        height: ...
        model: ...

        delegate: Loader {
            width: item.width
            height: root.rowHeight
            sourceComponent: myDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I use loader instead of directly assigning `myDelegate` to `myListView.delegate` is because I need the delegate to have a specific height that can't be changed from the where the delegate is declared.

Now, the problem is I can't access `index` property from where I assign the delegate:

```
// main.qml
MyComponent {
    myDelegate: Component {
        id: comp
        Button {
            onClicked {
                // this doesn't work
                console.log("index = " + index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although, I can access the index property inside the Loader:

```
// inside the loader
onLoaded:
{
    // works
    console.log(index); 
}
```

I also tried to create a property alias for it but it doesn't seem to be possible (it prints `Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "index"`)

Any solution?

Comment: did you try `property int myIndex: index` and then from within the delegate use `myIndex`?

Comment: @Amfasis Oh, that worked, thanks! I didn't try it at first because I thought that the property would stay the same when I remove a row, but it actually does change accordingly.